# How to check if a point is inside a rectangle?

Tags: analytic-geometry, computational-geometry

There is a point $(x,y)$, and a rectangle $a(x_1,y_1),b(x_2,y_2),c(x_3,y_3),d(x_4,y_4)$, how can one check if the point inside the rectangle?

[image]

Comment: sorry, I can't find proper tags for this question, please help me to improve it

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752725/finding-whether-a-point-lies-inside-a-rectangle-or-not

Comment: I have just read some of the answers and created some images and Python code for it: http://martin-thoma.com/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle/

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Let $P(x,y)$, and rectangle $A(x_1,y_1),B(x_2,y_2),C(x_3,y_3),D(x_4,y_4)$

Calculate the sum of areas of $\triangle APD, \triangle DPC, \triangle CPB, \triangle PBA$.

1. If this sum is greater than the area of the rectangle,  then $P(x,y)$ is outside  the rectangle.
2. Else if this sum is equal to the area of the rectangle (observe that this sum cannot be less than the latter),

   1. if area of any of the triangles is $0$, then  $P(x,y)$ is on the rectangle (in fact on that line corresponding to the triangle of area$=0$). Observe that the equality of the sum is necessary; it is not sufficient that area$=0$),
   2. else $P(x,y)$ is is inside the rectangle.

Acceptably this approach needs substantial amount of computation. This approach can be employed to any irregular polygon, too.

---

Another  way is to calculate the perpendicular distances of $P(x,y)$ from all the 4 lines $AB,CD, AD,BC$

To be inside the rectangle,
   the perpendicular distances from  $AB, P_{AB}$(say) and from $CD, P_{CD}$(say) must be less than $|AD|=|BC|$  and the perpendicular distances from  $AD, P_{AD}$(say) and from $BC, P_{BC}$(say) must be less than $|CD|=|AB|$. 
   Here , the areas of each of the four triangles < $\frac{1}{2}$the area of the rectangle.

1. If one of  the perpendicular distances is greater than the respective length, then $P(x,y)$ is outside  the rectangle.

   This essentially implies and is implied by the statement : the area of the respective triangle > $\frac{1}{2}$the area of the rectangle (as commented by Ben Voigt) as $\triangle APD=\frac{1}{2}AD\cdot P_{AD}$.
2. Else if $ P_{AB}=0$ and $P_{CD}=|AD|$ , then  $P(x,y)$ is on AB . So, $\triangle PBA=0$ and $\triangle PCD=\frac{1}{2}$the area of the rectangle.

   Observe that in this case, the remaining two perpendicular distances $P_{AD}, P_{BC}$ must be ≤ $|AB|=|CD|$, $P_{BC}=|AB|\implies P(x,y)$ is lies on AD i.e, P coincides with A as it is already on AB .

Comment: Perpendicular distances involve at least one suqre root operation, which I think is avoidable.

Comment: @Hagen: The squared perpendicular distance is good enough.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler, potentially fewer computations, and equally correct to test if the area of any triangle is greater than half the area of the rectangle?

Comment: @BenVoigt, who'll dare to disagree?

Comment: Also if the area of each 4 triangles are less than half of the area of the rectangle,   the point is inside. If $ \triangle APD=0$ and $2\triangle BPC=$ area of the rectangle and the area of the rest two triangle $<\frac{1}{2}$area of the rectangle,  the  point is on AD.

Comment: @lab: Areas are cross products, so you're just computing four vector products: no more, really, than any of the other answers. (except those who can get away with 2 vector products)

Comment: -1  I know that this can be only a symbolic action. There is a
simple solution (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle/190373#190373) for this simple problem. By accepting this solution and giving it so many votes a stutdent or programmer that is searching this forum for a solution of this simple problem will be pointed in the wrong direction.

Comment: It was awesome to read this post if only to get why This is a correct but unusable algorithm: infinite precision comparison is required for iterated operators (sqrt) and it is costly. Use the alternative for rectangles, or search ray casting algorithms for point in polygon problems.

Comment: For a polygon this method would require triangle area per each point which may be impractical and it would theoretically require infinite precision computation to determine the case. Better

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, sorry for replying in such an old thread. I was trying to implement the approach in your post to concave polygons(not just rectangles), and it seems that this area-method only works for the convex case. Or is there any way to adjust the approach for concave polygons? Thanks!

Answer (score 263):

$M$ of coordinates $(x,y)$ is inside the rectangle iff

$$(0<\textbf{AM}\cdot \textbf{AB}<\textbf{AB}\cdot \textbf{AB}) \land (0<\textbf{AM}\cdot \textbf{AD}<\textbf{AD}\cdot \textbf{AD})$$

(scalar products of vectors, $\land$ stands for logical AND).

Comment: Far more efficient than any of the triangle methods.  Why aren't these getting more votes?

Comment: @Erick: Probably because I added it late (and I don't know why this straightforward method was not proposed earlier here...)

Comment: Thanks @user1783444 ! I tried to provide something mathematically simple (other solutions may be better in practice...).

Comment: I'm not great with math - does this hold true for any rectangle orientation, with any order of rectangle vertices so long as they are clockwise/counterclockwise (my intuition says yes, but I'd like to know for sure)?

Comment: Shortly yes @bgoers. We impose the perpendicular projection of $\textbf{M}$ on $\textbf{AB}\;$ to be between $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$ and the perpendicular projection of $\textbf{M}$ on $\textbf{AD}\;$ to be between $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{D}$. The result will follow from the condition that $\textbf{AB}\;$ and $\textbf{AD}\;$ are perpendicular. This condition is thus required for this method to work as well as accurate positions (floating points values instead of nearest integers) for the positions. Fine continuation,

Comment: I'm confused by all the answers, is this the best way to do it in JavaScript?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper: well this is a mathematical answer and was the shortest I could think at but I didn't implement it. Perhaps that this linked [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752725/finding-whether-a-point-lies-inside-a-rectangle-or-not) will help you more (I noticed that the same method appeared there with some code...).

Comment: Thanks. I wrote it up in javascript here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37865332/276093

Comment: Glad the link helped @matt burns. Thanks for your answer and excellent continuation!

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Sorry I am not good at solving maths but the answer you referred to in the comment on Dec 29,2015 and the one @matt burns wrote use both `AM` and `BM` but your answer only uses`AM`. But do they yield the same result? And are these the same method? I am so confused.

Comment: @newguy: Well if $\,\textbf{AB}\;$ and $\,\textbf{DC}\;$ are parallel as well as $\,\textbf{AD}\;$ and $\,\textbf{BC}\;$ then the results should be the same (remember that this is a mathematical answer!). From my comment dated jun 10 '15 they simply chose to project $\,\textbf{M}\,$ on the other side of the rectangle (on $\,\textbf{BC}\;$ instead of $\,\textbf{AD}\,$) so that the methods are nearly the same with only some small differences for a not perfect rectangle. Note that Jonas Elfström's (possibly quicker) answer corresponds to mine. Cheers,

Comment: (instead of my $(0<\textbf{AM}\cdot \textbf{AB}<\textbf{AB}\cdot \textbf{AB})\:$ Jonas Elfström used the equivalent $\;(0<\textbf{AM}\cdot \textbf{AB})$ and $(\textbf{BM}\cdot \textbf{AB}<0)$. they are the same since $[\textbf{AM}\cdot \textbf{AB}-\textbf{AB}\cdot \textbf{AB}=(\textbf{AM}-\textbf{AB})\cdot \textbf{AB}]<0$)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thanks for clearing this up.Your answer and other comments under this answer help me big time.

Comment: Needs more explanation in the answer (not comments). Took me a while to decipher this.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni shouldn't this bet greater than or equals?

Comment: @PentaKon: I considered $(x,y)$ *inside* the rectangle and so the (strict for english speaking people...) inequalities but you may of course adapt the tests to your specific needs.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni And this of course generalizes to 3D, correctt? In this case, instead of projecting on sides, we should project on vectors normal to the faces right?

Comment: @user599310: yes and note that for a (perfect) cuboid the $3$ normal vectors are simply the $3$ orthogonal vectors (cuboid edges) starting from a corner!

Answer (score 40):

I would use a "point-in-convex-polygon" function; this works by checking whether the point is "to the left of" each of the four lines.

Comment: Or else on the same side as the center (mean) of the polygon.

Comment: Or else same side as any of the other vertices?

Answer (score 35):

For example, if all the triangles $ABP$, $BCP$, $CDP$, $DAP$ are positively oriented; for $ABP$ this can be tested by checking the sign of  $(x-x_1)\cdot(y-y_2)-(y-y_1)\cdot(x-x_2)$. This method generalizes to convex polygons.

Alternatively, find a transformation that makes the rectangle parallel to the axes. Apply the same transformation to your point at the test is simple. This is especially helpful if you want to test many points against the same rectangle.

Comment: I didn't understand what we're concluding by checking the sign of that expression, and how it relates to the point being inside the polygon. Could you please explain?

Comment: @arya_stark You can find if two points lie on the same side of a line by substituting the co-ordinates of the point in the line equation and checking their signs' agreement.

Answer (score 26):

Given how much attention this post has gotten and how long ago it was asked, I'm surprised that no one here mentioned the following method.

A rectangle is the image of the unit square under an [affine map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). Simply apply the inverse of this affine map to the point in question, and then check if the result is in the unit square or not.

To make things clear, consider the following image,
[image: affine map]

where the vectors in the pictures are $\mathbf{u} = c - d$, $\mathbf{v} = a - d$, and $\mathbf{w} = d$.

Since the legs of a rectangle are perpendicular, the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u} & \mathbf{v}\end{bmatrix}$ is [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) and so we even have a simple formula for the inverse:
$$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u} & \mathbf{v}\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u}^T/||u||^2 \\ \mathbf{v}^T/||v||^2\end{bmatrix}.$$

If you want to check many points for the same rectangle, this matrix can be easily precomputed and stored, so that you perform the (typically more expensive) division operations only once at the start. Then you only need to do a few multiplications, additions, and subtractions for each point you are testing.

This method also applies more generally to checking whether a point is in a parallelogram, though in the parallelogram case the matrix inverse does not take such a simple form.

Comment: Thanks Nick, came here and wanted to see this exact reply

Comment: I'm confused why isn't this post upvoted the most

Comment: @Amira I think because I posted this answer several years after the question was asked. By the way, this matrix formula, if you write it out and perform some algebraic manipulations, can be transformed into the mysterious formula in the highest upvoted answer by Raymond Manzoni.

Answer (score 17):

[image: Inside]
The point is **inside** the rectangle.

[image: Outside]
The point is **outside** the rectangle.

Let us define:
A: area of the rectangle
A<sub>i</sub>: areas of the triangles shown in the pictures. (i = 1, 2, 3, 4)
a<sub>i</sub>: lengths of the edges shown in the pictures. (i = 1, 2, 3, 4)
b<sub>i</sub>: lengths of the line segments connecting the point and the corners. (i = 1, 2, 3, 4)

**If the point is inside the rectangle, the following equation holds:**
$ \mathbf{A = A_1 + A_2 + A_3 + A_4} $

**If the point is outside the rectangle, the following inequality holds:**
$ \mathbf{A > A_1 + A_2 + A_3 + A_4} $

How do we calculate A, A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>, A<sub>3</sub>, A<sub>4</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>, a<sub>4</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>3</sub> and b<sub>4</sub>?

First we calculate the edge lengths:

$
a_1 = \sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2} \\
a_2 = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_3)^2 + (y_2 - y_3)^2} \\
a_3 = \sqrt{(x_3 - x_4)^2 + (y_3 - y_4)^2} \\
a_4 = \sqrt{(x_4 - x_1)^2 + (y_4 - y_1)^2}
$

Next we calculate the lengths of the line segments:

$
b_1 = \sqrt{(x_1 - x)^2 + (y_1 - y)^2} \\
b_2 = \sqrt{(x_2 - x)^2 + (y_2 - y)^2} \\
b_3 = \sqrt{(x_3 - x)^2 + (y_3 - y)^2} \\
b_4 = \sqrt{(x_4 - x)^2 + (y_4 - y)^2}
$

Then we calculate the areas using [Heron's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula):

$
A \,\,\, = a_1a_2 = a_2a_3 = a_3a_4 = a_4a_1 \\
u_1 = \frac{a_1 + b_1 + b_2}{2} \\
u_2 = \frac{a_2 + b_2 + b_3}{2} \\
u_3 = \frac{a_3 + b_3 + b_4}{2} \\
u_4 = \frac{a_4 + b_4 + b_1}{2} \\
A_1 = \sqrt{u_1(u_1 - a_1)(u_1 - b_1)(u_1 - b_2)} \\
A_2 = \sqrt{u_2(u_2 - a_2)(u_2 - b_2)(u_2 - b_3)} \\
A_3 = \sqrt{u_3(u_3 - a_3)(u_3 - b_3)(u_3 - b_4)} \\
A_4 = \sqrt{u_4(u_4 - a_4)(u_4 - b_4)(u_4 - b_1)}
$

Finally you can do the area test to check if the point is inside or outside the rectangle.

Comment: what is A=area is smaller than the right hand side?  I am getting that now in Matlab

Comment: @mLstudent33 That is not possible. You must have done a typo in your equations.

Comment: it works now after I checked that float values are within a tolerance.

Answer (score 16):

One of the simplest algorithms of coordinate plane geometry is a method of "Is the vector $\vec{w}$ clockwise or counterclockwise from the vector $\vec{v}$?"

The algorithm is to compute the cross product $\vec{v} \times \vec{w}$. If the sign is positive, then $\vec{w}$ is counter-clockwise from $\vec{v}$. If negative, it is clockwise.

This method gives an algorithm for answering the question "Which side of a line is a point on?"

e.g. consider the left line of your box, line $da$, directed from $d$ to $a$. The point $p=(x,y)$ is on the right side of this line if and only if the vector $dp$ is clockwise from $da$. So we can simply compute the cross product to learn if $p$ is on the correct side of $da$ or not.

Do this with all four lines, and you have your test.

---

If you're using the same four points a lot, we can get away with half as much work. We can use the dot product to compute "How long is one vector in the direction another is pointing?"

We can compute the dot product of $da$ with $dp$. If this number is greater than the dot product of $da$ with itself, then your point is too far up to be in the box. If this number is negative, the point is too far down to be in the box.

Because this checks two boundaries at once, we only have to do this twice: once with $da$ to get the up-down location, and once with $dc$ to get the left-right location.

---

EDIT: One of the general ideas at play is to try and make as much use of the dot product and cross product as you can, as they are computationally efficient ways of computing geometric information related to things like length, angle, and area.

So a common strategy for a problem of computational geometry is to try and phrase the problem in terms of things that can be answered with dot and cross products. If that's not immediately obvious, phrase it in terms of (directed) lengths, angles, and areas, and try to rephrase *those* in terms of dot and cross products.

My approach to the question was to express "which side of a line?" as a directed angle, allowing use of cross product.

Also, I used the dot product to compute distance along a direction parallel to one of the sides of the rectangle. You could compute the same thing as "perpendicular distance" from an adjacent side, which would let you use the cross product.

Some of the other answers express things in terms of the areas of triangles -- these are naturally computed cross products. One answer summed their magnitudes and compared with the area of the rectangle. Another looked at the direction of the areas instead (i.e. whether the triangles were positively oriented).

Answer (score 11):

You can use complex analysis to check (which is really overkill and probably not computationally efficient but still neat and generalizes to all polygons without any difficulty). Specifically, identify the point $(a,b)$ with the complex number $a+bi$. Let $\gamma$ parametrize the rectangle by going around once counterclockwise. By Cauchy integral formula we know that

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z-x-iy}dz = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 \mbox{ if (x,y) is in the rectangle} \\
       0 \mbox{ if (x,y) is outside the rectangle}
     \end{array}
   \right.$

and is not defined if (x,y) is on any of the four boundary segments.

The integral is over 4 strait line segments. On the strait line segment from $(x_2,y_2)$ to $(x_1,y_1)$, the integral is just

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{x_1-x_2+i(y_1-y_2)}{t(x_1-x_2+i(y_1-y_2))+x_2-x+i(y_2-y)} dt = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{t-w_1}$

where $w_1= \frac{x_2-x+i(y_2-y)}{x_2-x_1+i(y_2-y_1)}$. This integral can be done so long as $w_1 \not \in [0,1]$, which corresponds to (x,y) on the segment. The result is $\log(1-w_1)-\log(-w_1)$. Note that this is a holomorphic function of $w_1$ on $\mathbb{C} - [0,1]$, where we have adopted the branch cut for $\log$ as $\log(r e^i \theta)= \ln(r) + i \theta$ for $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi]$.

Summing over the four edges gives the left hand side above as $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^4 \log(1-w_j)- \log(w_j)$ where $w_2,w_3$, and $w_4$ are defined analogously to $w_1$. You only need compute this sum to sufficient precision to rule out it equaling either 0 or 1. As I said before this isn't usually a good way in practice, partially because logs are pretty computationally expensive, but it is a way to do this.

Comment: If you take the exponential of the sum, you get a product that can be evaluated without logs, it isn't *too* bad.

Answer (score 11):

How can there be no vector math solutions to this yet?

Let $(x',y')=(x-x_1,y-y_1)$ so that the point $(x_1,y_1)$ is the origin..  Then get the height and width of the rectangle

> $w = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}$
>
> $h = \sqrt{(x_4-x_1)^2 + (y_4-y_1)^2}$

And then see whether $(x',y')$ is within that rectangle

> $0 \leq x'{(x_2-x_1) \over w} + y'{(y_2-y_1) \over h} \leq w$
>
> $0 \leq x'{(x_4-x_1) \over w} + y'{(y_4-y_1) \over h} \leq h$

Done!  Way easier than the triangle methods--those are for generic convex polygons and are awesome if you have a convex polygon, but are overkill for a rectangle.

(It's even shorter to use the vector forms.  If your coordinates are $\vec{p},\dots,\vec{p_4}$ then subtract $\vec{p_1}$ from everyone to get $\vec{p'}, \vec{p_2'}, \vec{p_4'}$.  Then you're in the rectangle iff $0 \leq \vec{p'}\cdot\hat{p_2'} \leq p_2'$ and $0 \leq \vec{p'}\cdot\hat{p_4'} \leq p_4'$.)

Answer (score 11):

It is very easy.

Just divide Rectangle in 2 triangle
i.e.

```
1) a(x1,y1),b(x2,y2),c(x3,y3)
2) a(x1,y1),d(x4,y4),c(x3,y3)
```

> **Then, point is in Rectangle, if and only if point is in at least 1
>   triangle.**

Following is code for checking point in triangle :

```
float sign(fPoint p1, fPoint p2, fPoint p3)
{
  return (p1.x - p3.x) * (p2.y - p3.y) - (p2.x - p3.x) * (p1.y - p3.y);
}

bool PointInTriangle(fPoint pt, fPoint v1, fPoint v2, fPoint v3)
{
  bool b1, b2, b3;

  b1 = sign(pt, v1, v2) < 0.0f;
  b2 = sign(pt, v2, v3) < 0.0f;
  b3 = sign(pt, v3, v1) < 0.0f;

  return ((b1 == b2) && (b2 == b3));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, the basic tool to use answers the question "are two points on the same side of a line?"

If the equation of the line is $ax+by+c = 0$
and the points are $(x_i, y_i)$ for $i = 1, 2$,
compute $d_i = a x_i + b y_i + c$ for each $i$.
If the two $d_i$ have the same sign
(both $> 0$ or $< 0$ to avoid problems about being on the line), they are 
on the same side of the line.

We now use this. Compute the point that is the average of the
four vertices. We know that this is inside the rectangle - this will work for a triangle also, where this problem more commonly occurs.

For each line making up the rectangle, 
do the "two points on the same side of a line" test
using the average point and your test point. 
If the average point and your test are on the same side
for each line (though they may be on different sides for different lines), 
the point is inside the rectangle.

Doing it this way, there are no worries about orientation or
traversing the vertices of the rectangle in a certain order.

Comment: Instead of the average of the vertices why cant we just use any of the other vertices?

Comment: This guarantees that the point is inside.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the rectangle as defining a coordinate system with origin $A$ and basis vectors $v_1 = B-A$ and $v_2 = D-A$. We can find the point $p = (x,y)$ in terms of this coordinate system as $\left(\frac{(p - A)·v_1}{v_1·v_1}, \frac{(p - A)·v_2}{v_2·v_2}\right)$. The coordinates of this transformed point are within the range 0 to 1 if and only if the point is within the rectangle.

This is equivalent to [Raymond Manzoni's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle/190373#190373), but I thought it worth deriving in this fashion.

Answer (score 3):

This is intutition at work, but what if you found the distances from the vertices to the point and added them all up?

Your min would be the distances to the center of the rectangle and your max is the distances if your point was on one of the vertices.

For example, for a 3x4 triangle, you min would be 10 (two times your diagonal) and your max would be 12 (if your point was on a vertex). This is your range: the point is inside the rectangle, if your distances from the vertices to the point are within the range 10 to 12 (for a 3x4 rectangle).

Answer (score 3):

I had this observation and it may be useful (but may be wrong too, as I have not proved it formally, so this text is proposed as a comment rather than a formal answer).

A rectangle can be divided into four inner rectangles with no gaps and as a result, there would be $1$ point that is common to all resulting 4 inner rectangles. Let that point be $p1$ in the picture below.

$p1$, has the following property: We could draw 2 lines intersecting at $p1$ such that *each of the lines going through p1 is perpendicular on 1 of the rectangle sides*. For example, Line $DC$ is perpendicular on line segment $v1v2$ and Line $AB$ is perpendicular on line segment $v4v1$.

The above property of $p1$ can't be satisfied by any point outside the rectangle.

Now, given a point $p1$, and 4 points that represent the rectangle corners, we may apply the above property to determine if p1 lies within the rectangle or not.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check if your point is inside triangle a,b,c or inside triangle a,c,d. There are several methods for doing this. See e.g. http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-a-point-in-a-triangle

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was to divide rectangle to two triangles and apply some optimized method twice. It seemed to be more effective than @lab bhattacharjee's answer to me.

http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html

Answer (score 2):

Rotate the rectangle 4 boundary points and detection point so that the bottom left corner of the rectangle becomes the origin. Change the coordinates of the point relative to the bottom left of the rectangle. Do simple boundary check for x and y axes. Done.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we have to choose 2 adjacent sides of the rectangle and then form the equations that contains them. The second step is to create 2 equations that contains the 2 slopes of the equations of the 2 adjacent sides and the critical point. Now we'll equate the equation that contains a side of a rectangle with slope m to one equation that contains the critical point and the slope -1/m, and then will equate the left equations. We'll also take into account that each solution has to respect the inequalities that can be easily deduced by checking the coordinates of the 2 adjacent sides. If we get 2 intersection points that respect the inequalities, then the critical point is inside the rectangle.

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different coordinate system, and reduce the problem to the case when one of the rectangle's legs is on the x axis and the others parallel to the y. In this case, you just see if the x and y inequalities for the rectangle are satisfied by your point. By a change of coordinate system, I mean simply choosing one of the vertices of the rectangle to be the origin, and using two perpendicular unit vectors for each of the adjacent sides (to the corner). Then, since you know the length of the sides of the rectangle, you can easily deduce the necessary rectangle inequalities.

NB by rectangle inequalities I mean the necessary and sufficient inequalities that must be satisfied in order for a point to lie in a rectangle in the first case.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate $\perp$ distances of point $P$ from all sides of rectangle and check if any of the distances of point from opposite sides is greater than the distance between them (one of the side length of rectangle). If it is greater than it is outside otherwise inside.

Answer (score 1):

let pi, xi, yi be the coordinate of p, x and y in the ith dimension

```
for i=1 to n
    if polarity(pi-xi, pi-yi) != -1 return false;
return true;

bool polarity(z){
    // z == 0 needs to be filtered out
    if (z > 0) return 1;
    if (z < 0) return -1;
}

bool polarity(px, py) {
    if (px == py) return -1;    // only happens when x = p = y
    if (px == 0) return -1;
    if (py == 0) return -1;
    return polarity(px) * polarity(py);
}
```

Possible to replace multiplication with bool function.

Comment: You're assuming we have a specific rectangle. The OP seems to be asking about the general question where we don't know the values of $x_1, y_1,$ etc.

Comment: If you can figure out the sequence of triangles APD,...., it would be even simpler to determine the diagonals.  Also, you can try all combinations of corners and if you get a single combination correct, you've solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(1,2,3,4)$ be the numbering of vertices in common Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$.
For a *triangle* we define **local** (so-called isoparametric) coordinates $(\xi,\eta)$ as:
$$
\Delta = (x_2-x_1)(y_3-y_1)-(x_3-x_1)(y_2-y_1) \\
\xi  = [(y_3-y_1)(x-x_1)-(x_3-x_1)(y-y_1)]/\Delta \\
\eta = [(x_2-x_1)(y-y_1)-(y_2-y_1)(x-x_1)]/\Delta
$$
And the Inside-Outside function as:
$$
\operatorname{IO}(x,y) = \min(\xi,\eta,1-\xi-\eta)
$$
Then we have that a pont $(x,y)$ is inside the triangle if $\,\operatorname{IO}(x,y)\gt 0\,$,
it is outside the triangle if $\,\operatorname{IO}(x,y)\lt 0\,$ and it is on the boundary if
$\,\operatorname{IO}(x,y) = 0\,$.

More information and a useful application is found at:

- [2-D and 3-D Point Probes](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/sunall/suna57.htm)

From the following reference we have the details below.

- [Quadrilateral Interpolation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007116/quadrilateral-interpolation)

[image]

Analogously to a triangle we have for the quadrilateral, in local / isoparametric coordinates $(\xi,\eta)$:
$$
N_1(\xi,\eta) = \frac{1}{4}(1-\xi)(1-\eta) = \frac{1}{4}(1-\xi-\eta+\xi\eta)\\
N_2(\xi,\eta) = \frac{1}{4}(1+\xi)(1-\eta) = \frac{1}{4}(1+\xi-\eta-\xi\eta)\\
N_3(\xi,\eta) = \frac{1}{4}(1-\xi)(1+\eta) = \frac{1}{4}(1-\xi+\eta-\xi\eta)\\
N_4(\xi,\eta) = \frac{1}{4}(1+\xi)(1+\eta) = \frac{1}{4}(1+\xi+\eta+\xi\eta)
$$
The global (common Cartesian) coordinates $(x,y)$ are calculated herefrom:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = N_1(\xi,\eta)x_1 + N_2(\xi,\eta)x_2 + N_3(\xi,\eta)x_3 + N_4(\xi,\eta)x_4 \\
y = N_1(\xi,\eta)y_1 + N_2(\xi,\eta)y_2 + N_3(\xi,\eta)y_3 + N_4(\xi,\eta)y_4
\end{cases}
$$
It is trivial that the vertices are given by:
$$
(\xi,\eta)=(-1,-1) \;\rightarrow\; (x,y)=(x_1,y_1) \\
(\xi,\eta)=(+1,-1) \;\rightarrow\; (x,y)=(x_2,y_2) \\
(\xi,\eta)=(-1,+1) \;\rightarrow\; (x,y)=(x_3,y_3) \\
(\xi,\eta)=(+1,+1) \;\rightarrow\; (x,y)=(x_4,y_4)
$$
Using abbreviations $(A,B,C,D)$ may be helpful.
$$
\begin{cases}
x = A_x + B_x\xi + C_x\eta + D_x\xi\eta \\
y = A_y + B_y\xi + C_y\eta + D_y\xi\eta
\end{cases}
$$
It's easy to see that the constants are given by:
$$
A_x = \frac{1}{4}(+x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4) \quad ; \quad A_y = \frac{1}{4}(+y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4) \\
B_x = \frac{1}{4}(-x_1+x_2-x_3+x_4) \quad ; \quad B_y = \frac{1}{4}(-y_1+y_2-y_3+y_4) \\
C_x = \frac{1}{4}(-x_1-x_2+x_3+x_4) \quad ; \quad C_y = \frac{1}{4}(-y_1-y_2+y_3+y_4) \\
D_x = \frac{1}{4}(+x_1-x_2-x_3+x_4) \quad ; \quad D_y = \frac{1}{4}(+y_1-y_2-y_3+y_4)
$$
In general, calculating the local coordinates from the global ones is a highly non-trivial exercise.
But it seems that we are lucky: the rectangle in the question is a parallelogram. In that case,
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram) teaches us that
*The diagonals bisect each other*:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left(\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} x_4 \\ y_4 \end{bmatrix}\right) =
\frac{1}{2} \left(\begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y_3 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y_3 \end{bmatrix}\right)
$$
Consequently, for a parallelogram, the non-linear $\,\xi\eta\,$ factors drop out. So our equations become:
$$
\begin{cases}
B_x\xi + C_x\eta = x-A_x \\
B_y\xi + C_y\eta = y-A_y
\end{cases}
$$
Two linear equations in two unknowns which can be easily solved with Cramer's rule:
$$
\xi = \frac{B_x(y-A_y)-B_y(x-A_x)}{B_xC_y-B_yC_x} \\ \eta = \frac{C_y(x-A_x)-C_x(y-A_y)}{C_yB_x-C_xB_y}
$$
Now the Inside-Outside function for a general quadrilateral may be defined as:
$$
\operatorname{IO}(x,y) = \min\left[N_1(\xi,\eta),N_2(\xi,\eta),N_3(\xi,\eta),N_4(\xi,\eta)\right]
$$
Then we have that a point $(x,y)$ is inside the quadrilateral if $\,\operatorname{IO}(x,y)\gt 0\,$,
it is outside the quadrilateral if $\,\operatorname{IO}(x,y)\lt 0\,$ and it is on the boundary if
$\,\operatorname{IO}(x,y) = 0\,$. The calculations are quite feasible only for parallelograms.
Summarizing the recipe:

1. Calculate $(A_x,B_x,C_x)$ and $(A_y,B_y,C_y)$ from the vertex coordinates
2. Calculate $(\xi,\eta)$ from $(x,y)$ with the above Cramer's solution
3. Calculate the four shape functions $N_k(\xi,\eta) = (1\pm\xi)(1\pm\eta)/4$
4. Calculate the Inside-Outside function as the minimum of them

Answer (score 0):

find the equations of the lines and equate the distance from the point P TO THE GIVEN TWO Pairs of lines .if the point is inside the rectangle,the distances to the pairs will be less than the distances between the line in the pair