# How to determine a Triangle vertices by its coordinates?

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems

I have to solve this problem, yet I'm not sure what is asked.

> Given a triangle whose vertices are defined by its coordinates. Determine where is the point O with the given coordinates - inside or outside the triangle?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly known problem that reduces to a system of linear equations.
Take a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-a-point-in-a-triangle

Comment: Thank you :) just what I needed