# Check if a point is inside a rectangular shaped area (3D)?

Tags: 3d, area, computational-geometry, rectangles

I am having a hard time figuring out if a 3D point lies in a cuboid (like the one in the picture below). I found a lot of examples to check if a point lies inside a rectangle in a 2D space for example [this on](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle) but none for 3D space.

[image]

I have a cuboid in 3D space. This cuboid can be of any size and can have any rotation. I can calculate the vertices $P_1$ to $P_8$ of the cuboid.

Can anyone point me in a direction on how to determine if a point lies inside the cuboid?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The three important directions are $u=P_1-P_2$, $v=P_1-P_4$ and $w=P_1-P_5$.  They are three perpendicular edges of the rectangular box.

A point $x$ lies within the box when the three following constraints are respected:

- The dot product $u.x$ is between $u.P_1$ and $u.P_2$
- The dot product $v.x$ is between $v.P_1$ and $v.P_4$
- The dot product $w.x$ is between $w.P_1$ and $w.P_5$

---

EDIT:
If the edges are not perpendicular, you need vectors that are perpendicular to the faces of the box.  Using the cross-product, you can obtain them easily:
$$u=(P_1-P_4)\times(P_1-P_5)\\
v=(P_1-P_2)\times(P_1-P_5)\\
w=(P_1-P_2)\times(P_1-P_4)$$
then check the dot-products as before.

Comment: In the case of perpendicular edges the constraints are that all the three dot products must be valid right not just any one of them? Superb answer by the way

Comment: According to my testing in unity, I had to check if ux is between uP2 & uP1; if vx is between vP4 & vP1; and if wx is between wP5 & wP1 (the inverse order)

Comment: @Empy2 do I need to normalize the direction vectors u,v,w ?

Comment: @Kong No, $ku.x$ is between $ku.P_1$ and $ku.P_2$ whenever $u.x$ is between $u.P_1$ and $u.P_2$

Comment: Could somebody point me to a source for this? I see that it works, but I want to understand how, and I am not that much into geometry.

Comment: for a non-math guy, are these p1 p2 etc the Position vectors of the co-ordinates ? How can i translate my x,y,z co-ordinate into these P1, P2 , etc ?

Comment: $P1=(x_1,y_1,z_1), P2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and so on.

Comment: Can you please give some sources or explain, what is the reason behind these equations working the way they are working ? @Empy2

Comment: @UgoHed is correct. This answer needs to be updated.

Answer (score 10):

Given $p_1,p_2,p_4,p_5$ vertices of your cuboid, and $p_v$ the point to test for intersection with the cuboid, compute:
$$\begin{matrix}
i=p_2-p_1\\ 
j=p_4-p_1\\ 
k=p_5-p_1\\
v=p_v-p_1\\
\end{matrix}$$

then, if
$$\begin{matrix}
0<v\cdot i<i\cdot i\\
0<v\cdot j<j\cdot j\\
0<v\cdot k<k\cdot k
\end{matrix}$$
The point is within the cuboid.

Comment: I like this approach. Simple and clever.

Comment: for a non-math guy, are these p1 p2 etc the Position vectors of the co-ordinates ?
How can i translate my x,y,z co-ordinate into these P1, P2 , etc ?

Comment: p1 is a vector which represents the position of the front bottom left point of the box. the front bottom left point of the box, p1, should have x y z coordinates. p1 = (x, y, z). You can perform b - a by doing (bx - ax, by - ay, bz - az). The dots represent dot product. a dot b = (ax, ay, az) dot (bx, by, bz) = ax*bx + ay*by + az*bz

Comment: @TreyReynolds thanks alot ! This helped :D

Comment: Can you please give some sources or explain, what is the reason behind these equations working the way they are working ? @TreyReynolds

Answer (score 0):

Since 2-D problem is known, divide the problem into 3 parts.

Disregard z-coordinate. If any point is within box bounds $ x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1, $ select it and all other such points. Similarly y-z and z-x boxes.

Next choose points that the are common to three selections.