# Will points intersect with path with width

Tags: geometry

I want to be able to check if a list of points will hit a screwed rectangle (rhombus I think).

I start out with 2 point P and T, I want to create a rectangle between the 2 points. I have used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854043/drawing-rectangle-between-two-points-with-arbitrary-width to do this. This gives me 4 points A, B, C and D of the new rectangle.

I then want to check if the point M is withing this rectangle.

[image]
The two black dots are my points P and T, the black box is the rectangle I want to generate between the two dots, being X wide.
I then want to test if the red dots are withing the black box.

Comment: Added to the main post

Comment: Once we got your rectangle described properly, we could rotate the whole scene to get it orthogonally aligned to the coordinate axes. Then the test for inclusion is very simple.

Comment: Given $P$ and $T$ and the width $w$ of the rectangle is not enough information. Needed would be e.g. that $w$ is the length of the sides the points $P$ and $T$ sit on in the middle each.

Answer (score 0):

Once you got the coordinates of the vertices of your rectangle,
you can proceed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/190111/86776)