# Coordinate geometry triangle problem

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the equations which all points inside the triangle formed by the points $(1,3)$, $(5,0)$ and $(-1,2)$ must satisfy

Now the answer mentioned is $$3x+2y \ge 0$$$$2x+y-13 \ge0$$$$2x-3y-12 \le0$$

Now I found the equation of the triangular sides and tried to use the fact that any arbitrary point $(x,y)$ and the vertex of the triangle opposite to the side must lie on the same same and hence formed three equation but I couldn't reach the correct answer.

Please give hints only. You needn't do the calculation. Just give me suitable hints from where I can take my work ahead.

Comment: The approach is correct. Maybe a calculation mistake?

Comment: Find the area of $(x,y);(1,3),(5,0)$.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle

Comment: The answer seems wrong. The first line $3x+2y=0$ passes through the origin but no side of the triangle passes through the origin. Are you sure of the coordinates?

Comment: Actually, **all** the equations formed are in-correct.

Comment: They were mentioned in the answer. I couldn't get to that, that's why I asked the question. May be the answer is wrong.