# Determine whether a point is inside a square

Tags: vectors, 3d

I have a square given by the points $A(3,4,0)$, $B(-1,6,4)$, $C(-5,2,2)$ and $D(-1,0,2)$. I have shown that these points lie in the plane $x-2y+2z=-5$ and that they form the vertices of a square in that plane.
I need to determine whether the foot of the normal $Q$ closest to the point $P(-1,7,5)$  is inside or outside this square.
I found the foot to be $Q(-1,7,5)$ but I am not sure of a method determining whether is inside the square or not. How can I determine this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a point is inside a rectangle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle)