# Check if segment crosses circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I have 2 points $p_1$ and $p_2$ in a $2D$ plane. There are $N$ balls of radius $r$ scattered in the plane. I want to know which balls will be crossed by the segment $p_1 \rightarrow p_2$.

I did it using line-point distance, but obviously, when checking the balls, some of them who are not crossed by the segment are giving me false-positives, since they are crossed by the line formed from the points $p_1$ and $p_2$.

**Given $p_1$, $p_2$, $r$ and the position $(x,y)$ of a ball, how can I know if this ball is crossed by the segment?**

> In the image below, the green balls are crossed while the reds are not.

[image]

Comment: Why not just additionally check if the candidates are in  the band between $p_1$ and $p_2$?

Comment: What exactly to do you mean by “crossing” the ball? Does a line segment that’s completely within a ball “cross” it? Does a line segment with one endpoint within the ball “cross” is?

Comment: @amd the segment $p_1$ to $p_2$ crosses a ball if it passes through it or is tangent to it, like in the image.

Comment: So both endpoints must not be in the interior? What if one endpoint is on the ball’s boundary but the segment isn’t tangent to it?

Comment: I've just answered my own question, check the answer to understand. Maybe you can suggest a more optimized way of checking.

Answer (score 1):

Using coordinates, write $p_1=(x_{p_1},y_{p_2})$ and similarly for $p_2$. Now, you can parametrize the points of the segment between the two poins in this way:
\begin{equation}
p=\lambda(p_2-p_1)+p_1
\end{equation}

whith $\lambda\in[0,1]$ a parameter. This means that each point $p$ of the segment is written as
\begin{equation}
p=(\lambda(x_{p_2}-x_{p_1})+x_{p_1}, \lambda(y_{p_2}-y_{p_1})+y_{p_1}).
\end{equation}

Now, take a ball of center $(x,y)$ and radius $r$, compute its equation $(X-x)^2+(Y-y)^2=r^2$ and simply substitute the coordinates of the generic parametrized point $p$ inside the equation. The only variable now is the parameter $\lambda$, and the equation is quadratic. If this equation has some solution for $\lambda\in[0,1]$, the segment intersects the ball, otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by drawing a rectangle of height $2r$ and width $||p_2 - p_1||.$ If the center of a ball is inside the rectangle, it means the segment crosses it.

[image]

Comment: It would be interesting to know, how you determine that the center of the ball is inside the rectangle.

Comment: @user [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle) might help you.

Comment: Thank you! I think the answers proposed earlier were simpler and more effective.

Answer (score -1):

Checking the distance center-of-circle to line being less than radious is a good method.

To get only intersections with the segment, not the line, for those circles who intersect the line check also the distances from the center to both points $p1,p2$ to be less than radious.

Comment: You need a deeper discussion.

Comment: Wouldn’t the segment be completely in the interior of the circle in that case, and so doesn’t intersect it? This also misses lots of cases that do intersect the circle. For instance, when the segment passes through the center of the circle and the two endpoints are exterior to the circle and on opposite sides of it.