# Calculating the Area of Polygons in the Intersection of Two Grids

Tags: geometry, area

Let there be two identical $n\times n$ grids $A$ and $B$, each consisting of unit cells. Assume grid $B$ is translated by $(x, y)$ relative to grid $A$ and then rotated by an angle $\theta$. How can I calculate (or approximate) the area of all the small polygons created through the intersection of these two grids?

EDIT. The motivation for this problem is that each cell of grid $B$ is assigned a value and I want to use them to assign area-averaged values to cells of $A$ that are fully or partly covered by $B$.

My current solution is to divide each cell of $B$ into $d\times d$ smaller cells of the same value, and then add $\frac{1}{d ^ 2}$ times the value of the smaller cell to the corresponding cell of $A$ where its center-point falls into. Though it provides a good approximation, this can be computationally intensive for larger grids.

Comment: At the very least, you can find the corners of the polygon and hence calculate the area through the shoelace formula.

Comment: Could you say 1) If a histogram (intuitively approximate probability distribution) the form under which you want the result ?  2) What is your final motivation for this question ?

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure if I fully understand your first question but I have updated the problem with my motivation and what I have currently done to solve it.

Comment: Have you looked into Shapely?

Comment: Shapely for the geometric intersection operation, and numpy matrix algebra for the transformation itself

Comment: No worries, looking forward to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Fig. 1 : The "big picture" displaying many different cases.*

[image]

*Fig. 2 : An octagonal case (Fig. 2 and Fig. 3 are created by the program below "playing on" translation vector $V$).*

[image]

*Fig. 3 : The case of a quadrilateral.*

Your problem can be reduced to a classical issue : the determination of the intersection of 2 "filled" **convex** polygons $(A)$ and $(B)$ with vertices $A_1,A_2...$ and $B_1,B_2...$.

It is based on 2 principles (implemented as 2 functions in the Matlab program below)

- ("getting new points by side intersections") Testing whether side $A_pA_{p+1}$ intersects side $B_qB_{q+1}$ (of course, most of them have no intersection). Build a list $(L)$ of all these intersections.
- ("keeping inside vertices") Add to list $(L)$ all vertices $A_p$ which are inside polygon $(B)$ and, in a symmetrical way, all vertices $B_q$ which are inside polygon $(A)$.

Points of $(L)$ are the looked-for vertices of the intersection.

I have written (see below) a Matlab program in the case where polygons $(A)$ and $(B)$ are squares. $(A)$ has been taken WLOG to be the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ ; square $(B)$ is obtained from square $(A)$ by a rotation followed by a translation.

This program can be translated into another language ; you will just have to account for some "idiosyncrasies" of Matlab language I have used. For example, the last lines of the program use the "convhull" function ("convhull" = convex hull) yielding an anticlockwise ordering of points in $(L)$ and a computation of the common area.

Change the translation vector $V$ in order to see different cases.

> ```
> clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal
> %%%%%
> function I=inters(A,Ap,B,Bp) ; %  intersection of line segments [AA'] and [BB']
> I=[-1;-1]; % case where there is no intersection
> AAp=Ap-A;BBp=Bp-B;
> AB=B-A;AAp=Ap-A;
> d=det([AAp,BBp]);
> if d!=0
>    L=det([AB,BBp])/d;M=-det([AAp,AB])/d;
>    if (0<=L) && (L<=1) && (0<=M) && (M<=1) 
>       I=A+L*AAp;
>    end
> end;
> end;
> %%%%%
> function b=pointinsq(P,C); % boolean b=1 iff point P is inside square C
> % criteria : all det(AP_k,AP_{k+1}) must be >0
>    b=1;
>    for k=1:4
>       b=b && det([C(:,k)-P,C(:,k+1)-P])>=0;
>    end;  
> end; % 
> %%%%%
> t=pi/8;c=cos(t);s=sin(t);
> mA=[0,1,1,0,0
>     0,0,1,1,0]; % first square
>     Ro=[c -s
>         s c]; % rotation matrix
>      V=[0.3;-0.2]; % transl. vector
> mB=Ro*mA+V*ones(1,5); % second square
> L=[];
> for k=1:4 : % Adding to list the good vertices
>    if pointinsq(mB(:,k),mA);
>       L=[L,mB(:,k)]; % concatenation
>    end
>    if pointinsq(mA(:,k),mB);
>       L=[L,mA(:,k)];
>    end;
> end;
> for p=1:4
>    for q=1:4
>       I=inters(mA(:,p),mA(:,p+1),...
>                mB(:,q),mB(:,q+1));
>       if pointinsq(I,mA)
>          L=[L,I];
>       end;
>    end;
> end;
> plot(mA(1,:),mA(2,:),'r');
> plot(mB(1,:),mB(2,:),'b');
> if size(L,2)>0, % if nonvoid intersection
>    plot(L(1,:),L(2,:),'*k');
>    [K,Area]=convhull(L(1,:),L(2,:));
>    text(mean(L(1,:))-0.3,mean(Li(2,:)),['Area : ',num2str(Area)]);
>    L=L(:,K);
>    fill(L(1,:),L(2,:),'g');
> end;
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Pleasure. Do you know Matlab ?

Comment: For an astute way to check if a point is inside a rectangle (and in particular a square) see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190373/305862)

Comment: I do, though I have to convert it to Python because the rest of the project is in it. Shouldn't be that hard.